# Is there a Chrome extension to make RSS work like Opera?

Tags: google-chrome, rss

When you're opening RSS URL, Opera shows a button to subscribe.

When you're browsing the site with RSS meta tags, Opera shows an icon to subscribe.

Is there any Chrome add-ons with the same logic?

*Now I'm trying very stylish NewsSquares, but it can't do anything of these.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RSS Agreggator chrome extension work and look like Opera:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-rss-aggregator/ffhafkagcdhnhamiaecajogjcfgienom

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the official [RSS Subscription Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd)

Comment: Thanks. It is. Well, but can it work with any offline feed storage?